# Merging double Data in SQL with Group By

Tags: mysql, sql

i have a problem with a SQL Query

I have a Table like this.

|| KDNRS  || KUND    || ADM  || BS_1 || BS_2 || DATES_S ||
|| I-111111  || WKRST || A-008|| 0        || 0        || 18.09.2014 || 
|| I-222222 || EAAAAA ||  A-008 ||0        || 0        || 19.09.2014 || 
|| I-333333 || KENGAI   ||  A-008 ||0        || 0        || 06.11.2014 || 
|| I-111111  || WKRST || A-008 ||0        || 0        || 22.09.2014 || 
|| I-444444 || DRSCH || A-008 || 0        || 0        || 24.09.2014 || 
|| I-222222 || EAAAAA ||    A-008 || 0        || 0        || 10.09.2014 ||

Sorry for the bad way to display it.

Now i have double entries. Problem is, i want to display all shown columns but sum up the entires with the same KDNRS and KUND.
 ADM, BS_1 and BS_2 will be always the same because of my query. In addition i need the Date for my Query too, but it does not matter which is displayed after merging

My First Solution was

```
SELECT t_kds.KDNRS, 
t_stam.KUND, 
t_kds.ADM,
t_kds.BS_1, 
t_kds.BS_2, 
t_kds.DATE_S

FROM t_kds INNER JOIN t_stam ON t_kds.KDNRS = t_stam.KDNRS

GROUP BY t_kds.KDNRS, t_stam.KUND, t_kds.ADM, t_kds.BS_1, t_kds.BS_2, t_kds.DATE_S

WHERE (((t_kds.[ADM])=[Bitte ADM eingeben]) AND ((t_kds.BS_1)=0) AND ((t_kds.BS_2)=0) AND ((Max(t_kds.DATE_S))>#1/1/2014#))

ORDER BY t_kds.KDNRS;
```

But that did not work.

After that i tried this.

```
SELECT t_kds.KDNRS, 
t_stam.KUND, 
t_kds.ADM,
t_kds.BS_1, 
t_kds.BS_2, 
Max(t_kds.DATE_S) AS MaxDATE_S

FROM t_kds INNER JOIN t_stam ON t_kds.KDNRS = t_stam.KDNRS

GROUP BY t_kds.KDNRS, t_stam.KUND, t_kds.[ADM], t_kds.BS_1, t_kds.BS_2

HAVING (((t_kds.[ADM])='A-008') AND ((t_kds.BS_1)=0) AND ((t_kds.BS_2)=0) AND ((Max(t_kds.DATE_S))>#1/1/2014#))

ORDER BY t_kds.KDNRS;
```

with this code it seems to be working, but i am not sure... is this code ok? I have up to 1000 records, to compare them with the naked eye is impossible.
The Table result is

|| KDNRS  || KUND    || ADM  || BS_1 || BS_2 || DATES_S ||
|| I-222222 || EAAAAA ||  A-008 ||0        || 0        || 19.09.2014 || 
|| I-333333 || KENGAI   ||  A-008 ||0        || 0        || 06.11.2014 || 
|| I-111111  || WKRST || A-008 ||0        || 0        || 22.09.2014 || 
|| I-444444 || DRSCH || A-008 || 0        || 0        || 24.09.2014 ||

Comment: Wrong order, should be WHERE before GROUP BY. (And HAVING is for conditions on aggregate functions...)

Comment: This works, thank you. But the output is the same, so somehow my solution is working too? :-/ ^^

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this query

```
SELECT t_kds.KDNRS, 
       t_stam.KUND, 
       t_kds.ADM,
       t_kds.BS_1, 
       t_kds.BS_2, 
       SUBSTRING_INDEX(GROUP_CONCAT(t_kds.DATE_S ORDER BY t_kds.DATE_S DESC),',',1) AS date_val
    FROM t_kds
    GROUP BY t_kds.KDNRS
```